# Biztalk 2013r2 - Checking for multiple return schemas

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I'm sending data to a REST service, but need to make sure I can handle response issues generated from the XML-RPC end of the service.
The problem is the return schema for a fault is completely different to the standardised response schema.

I've changed my response types to System.Xml.XmlDocument, but I'm hoping there's an easier way of me checking for a specific schema being returned (so that I can then suspend the instance to be investigated from the console end).

Can I return multiple schemas from one response, and if so - what's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, you can return multiple different schemas on the same response port.  What is the issue you are having?  Is the response going back to an Orchestration?

Comment: I've given it a bit more thought and simplified it for myself.

Essentially, the API returns completely different schemas based on whether it succeeds or fails. If I fix the response schema to one specific one, it never technically errors in the console, so I've got no reflection of whether it worked or not.

What I'm going to do is return a generic System.XML.XmlDocument, then use some XPATH to scan the response message for a specific element ('Fault') - if true, I'll suspend the instance so I can diagnose it in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can return multiple different schemas on the same response port.

What you can do is create an internal schema, and create maps from all the external schema that map to it, and have to on your Inbound Maps in your send port.  Your could also set a field value, e.g. Succeeded to True or False, which you can either use for routing by promoting it and having subscriptions use the promoted property, or use it in an Orchestration (where distinguishing it would be enough).

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm missing a step here. I've created and apiResponseCheck schema with a distinguished 'success' field within. I've then created 2 response schemas; apiResponse and apiFaultResponse. I've then created 2 maps, 1 for the apiResponse to apiResponseCheck and 1 for the apiFaultResponse to the apiResponseCheck, I've then got a decision branch checking the apiResponseCheck for the 'Success' value, but when I build, it's alerting me that I've not constructed the apiResponseCheck msg (although I have, in the solicit-response constructor)? I feel I may be getting muddled up!

Comment: @mrc85 Check your receive shape and logical port that is connected to it, check what message that is set on there